# How can the word “no” be an adverb?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I am an English teacher and keen to learn things in detail to explain to my students. I would like a detailed explanation of why the word “no” can be an adverb if it is being used alone in response to some question. It is not qualifying anything in this usage.

Comment: OED says it's an "adverb" in contexts like *He just can't say No*. It's not exactly your typical example, but I think to some extent "adverb" is just the default bucket category for words that don't fit nicely into pigeonholes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you have a link for that? It sounds crazy since 'no' is being used as reported speech there and so can have no part of speech.

Comment: When used as a standalone reply, _no_ is not an adverb. It is an exclamation. The word _no_ has adverbial uses as well, but that’s not one of them.

Comment: @Mitch: Whenever I cite **OED** I mean the ***full*** (subscription-only) OED. [Here's the relevant link,](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/127440?rskey=XsLEd1&result=8#eid) if you're able to follow it. Perhaps you might like the categorisation more if we focus on other usages under the same OED heading, such as *to not take no for an answer*, or the "question tag" usage *The OED is a reputable source, no?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers the OED is the best reference for English word semantics, and is also very good. But that doesn't mean it doesn't have mistakes or that of the many entries it has, the appropriate entry was chosen. Also see JBJ's comments about how dictionaries aren't that great at POS.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Which entry for 'no'? The OED has many. Noun, adjective, verb, adverb, conjunction? And each of those has more than one main entry. I'm just having a hard time wading through all that text to find the "He just can't say 'no'" example.

Comment: @Mitch: So let me get this straight. You ask if I have any references to back up my claim. I point out that I'm citing *the premier reference work on the English language (bar **none**)*, and you dismiss this on the grounds that dictionaries sometimes contain mistakes. I'd buy that if we were talking about [**dord** in Merriam-Webster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dord), but not in the current context. Obviously I'm talking about the specific entry given in my link, even though you may not be able to follow it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Instead of insisting on (obviously excellent) authority, can you explain it to me instead? When you typed your first example above (He just can't say No) didn't you capitalize the word No because you meant not really to use the word but just to mention it -- He can't say the word "no"? How is that use adverbial? If I remarked "He can't say Ophthalmologist," would the word Ophthalmologist be an adverb?

Comment: @Chaim: My position is that if clever people like us can't immediately identify and agree on the correct terminology, it's because *that terminology isn't useful here*. Categories such as *noun, verb, adjective, adverb* don't so much reflect "real" differences - they just reflect *potentially useful* ways of analysing how language works. And in this case, regardless of what OED or anyone else says about the matter, I think it's effectively a pointless classification that does nothing to enhance people's understanding (and may in fact simply *confuse* them).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can access the OED online, but not via your link, and your link is not transparent enough to me to tell the exact OED entry, which is all I want to check. I'm not dismissing, I'm just skeptical (because I don't agree). And maybe reading the original most authoritative source might convince me otherwise. Also, can you address yourself the use/mention difficulty that Chaim mentions?

Comment: @Mitch: It's the first definition (1a) in my link above (repeated [here](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/127440?rskey=XsLEd1&result=8#eid)) *- expressing a negative reply to a question, request, etc., or introducing a correction of an erroneous opinion or assumption on the part of another person.* But note that I personally have no real opinion about "non-obvious" assignment of *any* POS terms, because I don't see how such almost arbitrary categorisations can enlighten us. I'm just  defending the OED *because* it's the OED.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK, I got parts of your link to work. You've linked to the OED entry "no, _adv.2_" (the 6th out of eleven entries), and definition 1a of that. So that clears up what the reference is, thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but there's lots to discuss here (and anyone can join. I've created the chat room [No, 'no', POS, OED](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55480/no-no-pos-oed) so that we can make longer messages (including relevant quotes form the OED).

Comment: A simple answer "No" is best regarded as a sentence substitute if it is given sensibly; it is a stand-in for say "I do not wish to have an ice-cream". How can a sentence be equated to an adverb?

Answer (score 4):

**'No'** has many functions in sentences. Adverbial function is one among them. '**No**' as a negative response to questions or requests is an adverb.

Examples: *Are you ready? - No. ( = No, I am not ready. It modifies the adjective ready)*

*Did you forget? - No. (= No, I did not forget. It modifies the verb forget)*

*Can you speak English fluently? - No. (= No, not fluently )*

'**No**' can also act as a noun, an adjective, a determiner etc.

Details and more examples can be had from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no) or any other dictionaries.

Comment: _No_ does not modify any adjectives or adverbs in your examples; _not_ does that. Exclamations do not modify anything.

Comment: 'No' meaning 'not' or "not so" — used to express negation, dissent, denial, or refusal". Is the 'no' in sentence "no, I'm not going"  an adverb or not?

Comment: It's not, and it doesn't ‘mean’ _not_ or _not so_ in the sense that the words are interchangeable; only in the sense that these are different words (possibly of different classes) that express the same semantic notion.

Comment: This is not my creation. See in M-W the definition No.3 under 'No' adverb and then comment. ( https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no)

Comment: Dictionaries are notoriously unreliable sources for word classification. Their job is meaning, not classification. M-W are lumping together three separate classes under the term _adverb_ here (adverb, determinative, and exclamation—though the determinative part is also subsumed under their _adjective_ heading). Adverbs modify verbs; when used as a standalone utterance, _no_ does not modify anything.

Comment: @Janus: Wouldn't you agree that "notoriously unreliable sources for word classification" primarily arises from the fact that dictionaries would obviously prefer to have just one "head entry" for each word? The online M-W seems to have just one such entry, but OED go the extra mile with 11 separate definitions (two of which are defined solely as *adverb*, and one as *adverb and noun*). This suggests to me that at least *they* think the categorisation is meaningful, even if I think it probably isn't.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet adverbs also modify adjectives and adverbs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're referring to the word "no" standing alone as a sentence.

> Al: Are you hungry?
>
> Bob: No.

Without reference to a part of speech, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no) gives this example of the word no:

> 3. not so -- used to express negation, dissent, denial, or refusal: No, I'm not going.

To me, that analysis suggests that "no" is an adjective. It is "not so." It is false.

Comment: The fact that _not so_ is an adjective (it isn’t, incidentally: this sense of _so_ is more adverbial than adjectival) doesn’t mean that _no_ is. Dictionaries don’t necessarily use words of the same class or syntactic function to explain and describe the meanings of their entries; that would often be too limiting. Pretty much all tests for adjective-ness will fail for _no_ in this sense (in fact in most senses).

Comment: I don't have much time for hair-splitting over terminology, but I don't think it's wise to disagree with the full OED here. They have 11 separate entries for **no**, three of which are defined as **adverbs**. The relevant one here is *Expressing a negative reply to a question, request, etc., or introducing a correction of an erroneous opinion or assumption on the part of another person.*

Comment: "Speak Mandarin. No speak the English."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet “no way”, “no idea”, “no hope”. Are these not adjectival in their sense? They certainly translate that way in many agglutinate languages. I realize this isn’t the litmus test, but it it strong support.

Comment: @ancepsinfans I'm not sure where you're coming from. I was writing (in March 2017) about "no" standing alone as a sentence, as a response to a yes-or-no question, not used as you're suggesting. But both uses are sentence fragments, so grammatical analysis is going to be loose. My loose analysis is that "no way" etc. mean "There is" no way (idea, hope), so that "no" is an adjective. But as I say, that was not the use we were then discussing.

Comment: @Chaim I wasn’t replying to you, but to Janus’s assertion in the first comment that the adjective test will fail for most senses of the word “no”. This is why I used “@Janus...” Sorry for any confusion.